# Jquery Sortable: Connect lists, with restrictions based on original list source

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have two sortable lists, A and B, created with Jquery's Sortable.

This is what I need:

Items that started out in list A should be sortable (also back and forth) between Lists A and B. However, items that started out in List B should never be moved to List A.

http://jsfiddle.net/f6hLaw7t/

```
<ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default">A: Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">A: Item 2</li>
</ul>


<ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">B: Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">B: Item 2</li>
</ul>

$(function() {
    $( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).sortable({
      connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
    }).disableSelection();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following example is separated into two main parts: **identifying the origin** of each draggable element and **checking if the drop is allowed**.

## Identifying the origin

First, we need to identify the origin from each element that will be dragged. The origin, in this case, was the `id` attribute of the list that first contained the element. The value is going to be stored in an attribute called `data-origin`.

```
$('.connectedSortable').find('li').attr('data-origin', function () {
    var $parent = $(this).parents('ul');
    return '#' + $parent.attr('id');
});
```

## Checking if the drop is allowed

You can use the [`receive`](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-receive) event to implement the algorithmn that will verify if the element is allowed to be dropped in the list.

To cancel the drop, simple call the method [`.cancel()`](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-cancel).

In order to make the example more generic, i´ve created an additional attribute `data-allow-from` in each list that indicates from which other lists it can receive elements.

Then we just create a simple callback function that will be invoked on the `receive` event of each list, that gets the origin of the dropped element and check if it's in the allowed list.

## Example

```js
function onReceive(event, ui) {

  var receiver = $(event.target),
    allowFrom = receiver.data('allow-from').split(',');

  var origin = $(ui.item).data('origin');

  var isAllowed = false;

  allowFrom.forEach(function(element) {
    if (element === origin) {
      isAllowed = true;
      return;
    }
  });

  if (!isAllowed) {
    $(ui.sender).sortable("cancel");
  }

}

$(function() {

  var opts = {
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
    receive: onReceive
  };

  $('.connectedSortable').sortable(opts).disableSelection();

  $('.connectedSortable').find('li').attr('data-origin', function() {
    var $parent = $(this).parents('ul');
    return '#' + $parent.attr('id');
  });

});
```

```css
.connectedSortable {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  width: 142px;
  min-height: 20px;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 0 0 0;
}
.connectedSortable li {
  margin: 0 5px 5px 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>ONLY A items</h1>
  <ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable" data-allow-from="#sortable1">
    <li class="ui-state-default">A: Item 1</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">A: Item 2</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div>
  <h1>A and B items</h1>
  <ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable" data-allow-from="#sortable1,#sortable2">
    <li class="ui-state-default">B: Item 1</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">B: Item 2</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div>
  <h1>A, B and C items</h1>
  <ul id="sortable3" class="connectedSortable" data-allow-from="#sortable1,#sortable2,#sortable3">
    <li class="ui-state-default">C: Item 1</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">C: Item 2</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.css">
```